# How to handle input(yes/ no) in buildspec.yml

Tags: linux, docker, yaml, command-line-interface, aws-codebuild

Im trying to perform codebuild in aws, and within my buildspec.yml i inserted a `sudo apt install python3-pip` command. And the aws codebuild run the buildspec file automatically, but during command execution
i get this: [image]
And i want it to answer with **[yes]** but the command in buildspec runs automatically and i cant interact with buildlog thats in AWS-Codebuild. what should i do in this case.

Comment: Found a  solution here -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo apt-get --yes install python3-pip
```

Which will answer yes automatically. I am unsure whether this works with `apt`.

Comment: I appreciate ur help, but i found a solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Usually ‘your Command << $"y\n"’ should work, but buildspec.yml in AWS codebuild did not work as my environment was ubuntu docker image.
But I was able to fix a similar issue
(1) create a shell script (which executes the same code above) in the build spec file
(2) executing the shell script created in step 1 thru the same build file.
e.g.

```
pre_build:
 commands:
   - echo '#!/bin/bash' > test.sh
   - echo 'your command  <<< $"y\n"' >> test.sh
   - chmod 755 ./test.sh
build:
 commands:
   - ls -l
   - echo currentdir $PWD
   # executing the created file
   - ./test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help i used something like printf 'Y\n' | <a command>,  i found it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I used this aand it worked, in case someone faced similar issue
$ printf 'Y\n' | 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line